# window.onload function is never executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

I'm running a simple page load, and in a separate javascript file that is linked, have the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Reached.");
}
```

However, in my HAML (essentially HTML) page, when I inspect the console on a page reload the output is never displayed in the console. Removing the `window.onload` makes it work, so it makes me suspect that perhaps something is stopping all of the elements from loading and so maybe the javascript never fires?

Here is my HAML code:

```
.row
  .col
    #main_container
        #main
           =haml :"content/videojsloader"
         = javascript_tag "scriptfiles/tester.js"
```

Indenting looks odd but its not an indenting issue the page loads fine in the browser.

Comment: is `tester.js` in your sources directory in the browser or in the network tab? Also, any console errors you notice?

Comment: Is the code loaded after the load event has fired? It is not going to trigger the event listener if it already ran.

Comment: Yes it's there @BenTheHumanMan, and epascarello I would assume not since I have the javascript to load after the haml content is loaded & also after the whole page loads? But maybe thats where I'm going wrong

Comment: `window.onload = function () {} ; console.log(document.readyState);`

Comment: Result is `loading` and then a console.log from `content/videojsloader` comes after it

Comment: Maybe you need to align the `= javascript_tag "scriptfiles/tester.js"` with the `#main` line, I did some tests and failed with your current code (in this case one space make the difference).

Comment: Hi, thanks but the aligning is fine it just misaligned in the stack overflow. In the editor, the lines are aligned and it doesn't work.